# iOS---Button causing unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f803a59cc50

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I have 3 buttons in my view, one button can change the background color of words in text view and that one work fine.One button can change outline of words in text view.This one emerge error every time i click.

Here is my error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException 
and Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT
```

And system do not know exactly which part crash,so i look into log navigator.    Here is my log navigator log :

```
2015-01-21 17:42:04.482   Attributer[2592:79541] -[ViewController outlineBodySelection]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f803a59cc50
2015-01-21 17:42:04.485 Attributer[2592:79541] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController outlineBodySelection]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f803a59cc50'
```

Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *headline;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *body;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)changeBodySelectionColourToMatchBackgroundOfButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.body.textStorage addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                  value:sender.backgroundColor
                                  range:self.body.selectedRange];
}


- (IBAction)outlineBodySelection
{
    [self.body.textStorage addAttributes:@{ NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @-3,
                                            NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor] }range:self.body.selectedRange];
}

- (IBAction)unoutlineBodySelection
{
    [self.body.textStorage removeAttribute:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName range:self.body.selectedRange];
}
@end
```

I suppose the last two class emerge error,but where did it go wrong,how can i fix it?
Somebody help me,please.

Comment: can u show the code of **One button can change outline of words**

Comment: outlineBodySelection check that is connected to ibaction

Comment: Enable `exception brakepoint` and try to crash your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing is ok from your side that i guess , but lets check once the connection from outlet whether from story board or XIB .

may be some connection loss or wrong connection which has mention like ! mark

else perfect from your side

Comment: I check my connection inspector.My outlineBodySelection disconnect with Outline Touch Up Inside.I am new to x-code.Really thank you for your time,it's been really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try making an outlet to your button and add this code to your button in `viewDidLoad`

```
[mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(outlineBodySelection) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen if you've connect a button to an IBAction that doesn't exist anymore (or has been renamed). check your connection once.

Answer (score -2):

An IBAction method has the format

```
-(IBAction)name:(id)sender
```

Comment: Well i understand that, but i am learning Stanford iOS7 CS193P lessons,and it did not add sender ,and i do not look for button to determine how to do it.

Comment: Your implying this is mandatory, you should elaborate a better answer, especially since the OP just said they were learning. Knowledge is free, free to give and free to get. Explain what sender actually does